# My menu repeats itself too many times when I enter a string of characters

Tags: c++

So here's my code

```
do
{
    cout << "Welcome to our Coffee Shop! Here are the options: " << endl;
    cout << "C - Coffee ($1.50)" << endl;
    cout << "T - Tea ($1.00)" << endl;
    cout << "S - Soda ($1.00)" << endl;
    cout << "J - Juice ($1.50)" << endl;
    cout << "M - Manager Special ($2.00)" << endl;
    cout << "X - Finish Order" << endl;
    cout << "What drink would you like? Enter C, T, S, J, M, or X." << endl;
    cin >> input;

    //does certain actions for a certain character
    if(input)
    {
        switch(input)
        {
            case 'C':
            case 'c': total += coffeePrice;
                    coffeeCount++;
                cout << "Thanks! You have ordered coffee." << endl;
                break;
            case 'T':
            case 't': total += teaPrice;
                teaCount++;
                cout << "Thanks! You have ordered tea." << endl;
                break;
            case 'S':
            case 's': total += sodaPrice;
                sodaCount++;
                cout << "Thanks! You have ordered soda." << endl;
                break;
            case 'J':
            case 'j': total += juicePrice;
                juiceCount++;
                cout << "Thanks! You have ordered juice." << endl;
                break;
            case 'M':
            case 'm': total += specialPrice;
                specialCount++;
                cout << "Thanks! You have ordered the manager special." << endl;
                break;

            default:
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                break;

        }
    }
    else
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    }
```

I've been trying to make a menu that only reads one character and does something as a result. The problem is when I enter a string that has multiple c's like "cccc" the menu repeats itself 4 times. Or if I enter a string that has some c's and other's that are not correct responses like, "ccddcc" the menu will say thanks for the coffee twice then repeat the menu twice and then say thanks for the coffee twice again. Is there a way to stop this from happening. I just want it to ignore any response other than a 'c' or a correct menu option.

Comment: read a whole line.

Comment: `if(input)` -- What is your intention with that statement?  And what variable type is `input`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would think the problem here is, is that `input`'is a char.  Thus, when you input cccc, it will read in the first char and move on, come back and see that there are still more c's in the std input waiting to be processed, so it will take that next c and process again.  I would recommend making your `input` var a string, and then if that string was greater than size 1, either leave or just use the first char.

```
char input[256]; // Could probably be a string, but I am used to C for this
do
{
cout << "Welcome to our Coffee Shop! Here are the options: " << endl;
cout << "C - Coffee ($1.50)" << endl;
cout << "T - Tea ($1.00)" << endl;
cout << "S - Soda ($1.00)" << endl;
cout << "J - Juice ($1.50)" << endl;
cout << "M - Manager Special ($2.00)" << endl;
cout << "X - Finish Order" << endl;
cout << "What drink would you like? Enter C, T, S, J, M, or X." << endl;
cin >> input;

switch(input[0])
{
    case 'C':
    case 'c': total += coffeePrice;
            coffeeCount++;
        cout << "Thanks! You have ordered coffee." << endl;
        break;
    case 'T':
    case 't': total += teaPrice;
        teaCount++;
        cout << "Thanks! You have ordered tea." << endl;
        break;
    case 'S':
    case 's': total += sodaPrice;
        sodaCount++;
        cout << "Thanks! You have ordered soda." << endl;
        break;
    case 'J':
    case 'j': total += juicePrice;
        juiceCount++;
        cout << "Thanks! You have ordered juice." << endl;
        break;
    case 'M':
    case 'm': total += specialPrice;
        specialCount++;
        cout << "Thanks! You have ordered the manager special." << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        break;
    }
}
else
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

}
```